# how to detect a connected Unix domain datagram socket was closed

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

app A and app B created Unix domain datagram socket,A call `connect` to connect B,so A can use `read` and `write` 0r `send` and  `recv` to communicate with B.but if B crashed,A will block at `recv`.B restart,sending msg to A will get error 1 operation not permitted.is there any way  A can detect B crashed ?

OS:Ubuntu 18.04  kernel 4.18.0

Comment: Since you have this tagged linux, consider using a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` socket instead of datagram.

Comment: No, there is no way to distinguish between B that has crashed and B that just has nothing to say at the moment.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I suspect there's some sort of kludge-on-a-kludge solution using an `lsof`-type approach of stomping all through `/proc` seeing if B still has an open socket to the Unix-domain socket...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect connection errors, a connection-orientated socket might be more appropriate, like `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_SEQPACKET`

From the man page of [socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html):

> ...
>
> If a piece of data for which the peer protocol has buffer space cannot be successfully transmitted within a reasonable length of time, then the connection is considered to be dead.  When `SO_KEEPALIVE` is enabled on the socket the protocol checks in a protocol-specific manner if the other end is still alive.
>
> ...
>
> `SOCK_SEQPACKET` sockets employ the same system calls as `SOCK_STREAM` sockets.

Nonblocking reads can be achieved via the `O_NONBLOCK` flag (on the descriptor) or the `recv` flag `MSG_DONTWAIT`.

Connection error detection on connectionless protocols has to be implemented in the application. You could implement a simple ping/heartbeat mechanism, where a client has to send (empty) packets within a specific time interval to indicate that it is still alive or still participating in the communication.

**Edit:** I've used TCP/UDP synonymously for `SOCK_STREAM`/`SOCK_DGRAM` (as the user Shawn pointed out in the comments below).

Comment: OP is using unix/local sockets. No UDP or TCP involved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, and the solutions that I found on the web did not entirely convince me. Therefore, I came up with this:

```c
// Client: replace every close() with this close_dgram_socket():

int close_dgram_socket(int fd)
{
   if (send(fd, "Bye-bye.", 8) == -1)
       perror("send");
   close(fd)
}
```

```c
// Server loop:
do
{ 
    fd_set readfds;   FD_ZERO(&readfds);   FD_SET(fd, &readfds);
    struct timeval timeout = { 0, 300000 };   // 300 ms
    if (select(fd+1, &readfds, 0, 0, &timeout) == 0)   // nothing reveived
    {
        if (kill(getppid(), 0) 
            break; // client has died
        else               
            continue;
    }
    rx_len = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
} while(rx_len != 8 || strncmp(buffer, "Bye-bye.", 8));

close(fd);   // peer has closed, so do we.
```

The idea is that (1) the server sends a Bye-bye datagram if she closes the socket orderly and (2) the client checks with `kill()` if the server is still alive to handle the case where the server crashes and cannot send the Bye-bye datagram. Works fine for `socketpair()` but not for UDP.